# Options for Cash only Buyout due to Company Merger

Tags: united-states, stocks, corporate-acquisition

On 12/3/15 Company shareholders of a company in Florida USA, voted to be acquired by a company in Nova Scotia, and the merger will take place in 2016.

I was not in favor of this.  This will be strictly a cash buyout, leaving me, and all other of the Florida shareholders with cash only.

As far as I can see, all this does for me is trigger a tax event where I will have to pay short term capital gains in Tax Year 2016.  The Florida company  will cease to exist.  There will be no stock acquisition for the Florida  shareholders, cash only.

This doesn't seem like a good deal to me, but that's history.

What are my options, if any, in how to deal with a buyout that forced me to sell, and accept cash only for my Florida USA company shares?

Comment: what do you mean "how to deal"? Are you asking about your options to prevent an already approved transaction? Only through courts.

Answer (score 2):

> What are my options, if any, in how to deal with a buyout that forced me to sell, and accept cash only for my Florida USA company shares?

Options are limited;

- You can raise a grievance on the company board saying minority shareholder view are affected. This may not help much as the sale would anyway be scrutinized and approved by regulators. Plus it has passed by overwhelming majority of shareholders.
- Get a court injunction, which again is a long drawn process and may not guarantee desired results. see if you can garner support and get a law firm who would work pro-bono.
- Sit back and pay the required tax. I guess the price was at premium to the listing price and net you would have made decent profit